# Update em outra linha na mesma tabela pela Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Existe alguma maneira de efetuar um update na mesma tabela, sendo em outra linha, através de um `after insert` ou `before insert`?

Comment: Sim tem. Usando procedure

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com essa [resposta do Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12878145/2099835), isso que você deseja não é possível no MySql. Trecho da [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

Um alternativa sugerida na mesma resposta é criar uma `stored procedure` que faça a ação da `trigger` mais o `update` junto de uma mesma `transaction`.

Comment: Por favor, poderia postar um exemplo...